# Improve speed of MySQL Update query with Inner Join and Where

Tags: mysql

I have an update query that is running slow and wanted to see if i could improve performance

Here is the query

```
update appmaster a
  INNER JOIN appid b ON a.activity = b.activity
  SET a.activity_id = b.activity_id
  WHERE a.activity_id IS null
```

appmaster contains about 9 millions records but less than 1 million of those have activity_id that is null

appid contains 171,000 records

I have an tried setting up an index on activity for both tables but doesn't seem to help.
I would set an index on appmaster activity_id because that is my where condition but that is the value im setting.

Any ideas?

appmaster table

```
CREATE TABLE appfiltration.appmaster (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  activity varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  class varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  device varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  version varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  theme varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  upload_date date DEFAULT NULL,
  activity_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX idx_activity (activity)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 9457807
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 136
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

appid table

```
CREATE TABLE appfiltration.appid (
  activity_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  activity varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  result int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  change1 float DEFAULT NULL,
  result_last int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  change2 float DEFAULT NULL,
  result_last2 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (activity_id, activity)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 251064
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 63
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

results from

```
EXPLAIN SELECT a.activity_id, b.activity_id 
FROM appmaster a 
JOIN appid b ON a.activity = b.activity 
WHERE a.activity_id IS NULL
```

[image]

Comment: Show your `CREATE TABLE` statements, and the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT a.activity_id, b.activity_id FROM appmaster a JOIN appid b ON a.activity = b.activity WHERE a.activity_id IS NULL`

Comment: update question with details

Comment: So, we can see that it queries b (appid) _first_, and then looks up appmaster records based on activity, and only then checks for NULL, so effectively, the entire table appmaster is scanned. You've got serveral options, one of which is indeed setting a proper index, but you might also check what performance a `STRAIGHT_JOIN` gives you.